# Absolute image position (dont allow to image go outide the div)

Tags: html, css, image

I have tried to search everywhere, but cant find out how to prevent image to stay in its parent div when image have absolute positioning (when zooming image its go outside of the div). hidden overflow not helping at this point. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you absolutely-position an element, it will position itself inside the nearest positioned parent. So, add a `position: relative` to the CSS of your element's parent.

To make sure the parent contains the positioned element, you'll want to add `overflow:auto` to the parent's CSS as well.

Comment: Thanks, now the div hides image overflow. But maybe there is a way when image goes out of div boundaries not to hide, but push back to div (I need that div borders act like a wall not allow image overflow it). Hope you understand :)

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work the way you're intending. You might want to position using `right` if you don't want it to overflow to the right (vice-versa for left-positioned elements).

Answer (score 1):

Add this style to the image:

```
 style="width:inherit; height:inherit;"
```

Answer (score 1):

add `position: relative`, to the parent div..

```
.parent_div {position: relative;}
.parent_div img {position: absolute; top: number; right: number;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
max-width: 100%
```